# 複数ページのテーブルをスクレイピングした結果をすべてCSV出力する

Tags: python

複数ページのテーブルをスクレイピングすることはできているのですが、その取得結果すべてをCSVに出力できずに困っています。
組んでみたコードでは、2番めのURLから取得したテーブルのみが、CSVとして出力されています。
すべてのURLから取得したテーブルをすべてCSVに出力するための工夫をご教示ください。

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
urls = ['http://honya.univ.coop/ranking_lst.php?rankingcd=001',
'http://honya.univ.coop/ranking_lst.php?rankingcd=002',
]

for url in urls:
  html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
  table = bsObj.findAll("table", {"class":"rankingTable"})[0]
  tables = table.findAll("tr")
  print(tables)

  with open("newbooks.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in tables:
        csvRow = []
        for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
            csvRow.append(cell.get_text())
        writer.writerow(csvRow)

pd.read_csv("newbooks.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

現状のコードでは `open` でファイルを開く時に上書きモード `w` が指定されているので、ループ処理でファイルを開くたびにリセットされ、最後の結果だけが出力されている状態なのだと思います。

以下の通りファイルオープン時に **追記モード** `a` を指定してみてください。

```py
open("newbooks.csv", "a", encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございました。無事にすべて出力できました。

Answer (score 1):

pandas には [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) というメソッドがありますので、それを使うのも良いかと思います。

```
import pandas as pd

urls = [
  'http://honya.univ.coop/ranking_lst.php?rankingcd=001',
  'http://honya.univ.coop/ranking_lst.php?rankingcd=002',
]

df = pd.concat(
  [pd.concat(pd.read_html(url, header=0, attrs={'class': 'rankingTable'}), axis=0)
   for url in urls],
  axis=0)
df.to_csv('newbooks.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

**newbooks.csv**

```
順位,書名,著者,出版社,本体価格,発売月,ISBN
1,大衆の反逆,ホセ・オルテガ・イ・ガセト,岩波書店,"1,070 円",2020/04,9784003423110
2,トラペジウム,高山一実,ＫＡＤＯＫＡＷＡ,680 円,2020/04,9784041026441
3,勉強の哲学,千葉雅也,文藝春秋,700 円,2020/03,9784167914639
                       :

28,侘助ノ白,佐伯泰英,文藝春秋,730 円,2020/05,9784167914943
29,対談集歴史を考える,司馬遼太郎,文藝春秋,670 円,2020/05,9784167914998
30,まるごと腐女子のつづ井さん,つづ井,文藝春秋,900 円,2020/05,9784167915001
1,教育は何を評価してきたのか,本田由紀,岩波書店,840 円,2020/03,9784004318293
2,感染症は実在しない,岩田健太郎,集英社インターナショナル,980 円,2020/04,9784797680522
3,５Ｇ,森川博之,岩波書店,860 円,2020/04,9784004318316
                       :
```

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございました。こちらの方法でも取得できることが学べました。